# How to check whether some SKPhysicsBody in contained in another

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I've reviewed similar questions and do believe I'm asking about different thing.

I have a player node which has it's own body and I want to check when it's been moved to some part of the level (exit node). Examples of this may be putting some dynamic item in a box, or parking a car at the specific place.

In my case player is SKSpriteNode with physicsBody created from similar texture (bodyWithTexture) and exit is SKNode with no visual and physicsBody created from polygon path (4 points, non rectangle).

I have a code which does something I wan't, but I do believe there maybe some cases it's doing something I don't want and there are better ways to do it.

```
    int contactsCount = 0;    
    - (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{
        if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) & exitCategory) {
            contactsCount++;
            if (contactsCount == 4) {
                [player runAction:[SKAction colorizeWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] colorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:1.0] completion:^{
                    self.physicsWorld.speed = 0;
                }];
            }
            return;
        }

        [player runAction:[SKAction colorizeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] colorBlendFactor:1.0 duration:1.0] completion:^{
            self.physicsWorld.speed = 0;
        }];
    }

    - (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{
        if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) & exitCategory) {
            contactsCount--;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What sort of nodes are the physics bodies attached to?  SKNode implements containsPoint.  One node contains another if all of the latter's vertices are contained by the former.

Comment: @danh I've added details about it.

Comment: Yes.  I think it will be more robust to check this declaratively based on polygon containment.  You can use `CGPathContainsPoint` on the path that describes the exit.  Test it with each corner of the player's frame.  Be sure to do the comparison in the same coordinate system (probably by using convertPoint:toNode: to go from player coords to exit coords).